# Direct Update not working in Worklight 6.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When i try to update the build for iphone in Worklight 6.2, It is giving the below Exception. App is working fine for android even Direct Update is happening as expected. But, For iPhone it works fine when a new ipa is built and installed. Whenever the build is updated,it throws below exception(only for iOS).

[11/6/15 17:12:04:816 SGT] 00000095 com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext                    E FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule' failed. Failed to delete original file 'C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\wlserver\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\abcApp\abcApp\widget-resources\abc-iphone-1.0-7ff817131d192dbb7139e9b4937811096e67a866\direct-update\abc-iphone-1.0-default.zip_temp.base64' after copy to 'C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\wlserver\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\abcApp\abcApp\widget-resources\abc-iphone-1.0-7ff817131d192dbb7139e9b4937811096e67a866\direct-update\abc-iphone-1.0-default.zip.base64'. [project abcApp]
com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: Failed to create base64 encoded file for for abc@iphone@v1.0 for skin: default
                at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DirectUpdateAuthenticator.getUpdateZipLength(DirectUpdateAuthenticator.java:345)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DirectUpdateAuthenticator.testSkin(DirectUpdateAuthenticator.java:245)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DirectUpdateAuthenticator.processRequest(DirectUpdateAuthenticator.java:130)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.processRequest(LoginContext.java:200)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:557)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:457)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:431)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:230)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:78)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
                at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
                at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\wlserver\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\abcApp\abcApp\widget-resources\abc-iphone-1.0-7ff817131d192dbb7139e9b4937811096e67a866\direct-update\abc-iphone-1.0-default.zip_temp.base64' after copy to 'C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\wlserver\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\abcApp\abcApp\widget-resources\abc-iphone-1.0-7ff817131d192dbb7139e9b4937811096e67a866\direct-update\abc-iphone-1.0-default.zip.base64'
                at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2109)
                at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.GetApplicationUpdatesHandler.getBase64EncodedFile(GetApplicationUpdatesHandler.java:418)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DirectUpdateAuthenticator.getUpdateZipLength(DirectUpdateAuthenticator.java:343)
                ... 19 more

[11/6/15 17:12:04:816 SGT] 00000095 com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext                    E FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule, User Identity Not available. [project abcApp] [project abcApp]
[11/6/15 17:12:05:565 SGT] 00000095 com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext                    E FWLSE0059E: Login into realm 'WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule' failed. Failed to delete original file 'C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\wlserver\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\abcApp\abcApp\widget-resources\abc-iphone-1.0-7ff817131d192dbb7139e9b4937811096e67a866\direct-update\abc-iphone-1.0-default.zip_temp.base64' after copy to 'C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\wlserver\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\abcApp\abcApp\widget-resources\abc-iphone-1.0-7ff817131d192dbb7139e9b4937811096e67a866\direct-update\abc-iphone-1.0-default.zip.base64'. [project abcApp]
com.worklight.gadgets.GadgetRuntimeException: Failed to create base64 encoded file for for abc@iphone@v1.0 for skin: default
                at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DirectUpdateAuthenticator.getUpdateZipLength(DirectUpdateAuthenticator.java:345)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DirectUpdateAuthenticator.testSkin(DirectUpdateAuthenticator.java:245)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DirectUpdateAuthenticator.processRequest(DirectUpdateAuthenticator.java:130)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext.processRequest(LoginContext.java:200)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.checkAuthentication(AuthenticationContext.java:557)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.processRealms(AuthenticationContext.java:457)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:431)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:230)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:78)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
                at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
                at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete original file 'C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\wlserver\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\abcApp\abcApp\widget-resources\abc-iphone-1.0-7ff817131d192dbb7139e9b4937811096e67a866\direct-update\abc-iphone-1.0-default.zip_temp.base64' after copy to 'C:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\wlserver\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\75\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\abcApp\abcApp\widget-resources\abc-iphone-1.0-7ff817131d192dbb7139e9b4937811096e67a866\direct-update\abc-iphone-1.0-default.zip.base64'
                at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2109)
                at com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.GetApplicationUpdatesHandler.getBase64EncodedFile(GetApplicationUpdatesHandler.java:418)
                at com.worklight.core.auth.ext.DirectUpdateAuthenticator.getUpdateZipLength(DirectUpdateAuthenticator.java:343)
                ... 19 more

[11/6/15 17:12:05:565 SGT] 00000095 com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginContext                    E FWLSE0117E: Error code: 4, error description: AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, error message: An error occurred while performing authentication using loginModule WLDirectUpdateNullLoginModule, User Identity Not available. [project abcApp] [project abcApp]

Answer (score 0):

This is a recent regression in Worklight 6.2, that was fixed.

Please download and install the latest 6.2 iFix from IBM Fix Central (the fix is in the server component so make sure to install That).

Comment: Thanks Idan. We have tried updating the iFix(6.2.0.1-WL-Server-IF201510081615) but the issue still persists. Could u pls confirm is this the right iFix to be installed.  
 Earlier it seems to be working without any issue. But this issue has occured recently. Only change from previous build to this build is that we are using Custom Login Module for this build. But even with this change android is working fine as expected, only iOS seems to be affected.

Comment: No, this iFix is too old. I think that the fix was not uploaded yet to IBM Fix Central then. In this case you can open a PMR and request the latest internal iFix. That should solve it then.

Comment: We have updated the latest iFix received via PMR (6.2.0.1-WL-StudioP2-IF201510252301.zip and 6.2.0.1-WL-Server-IF201510252301.zip).
Now, the problem is Liberty Profile is not responding properly. It goes into hung mode after sometime and does not give any error messages.
Liberty profile version is 8.5.5.0. Because of this intermittent behaviour, we are unable to proceed to check on the actual issue(Direct Update with iOS).